# printing dict variable from imported file in OOP

Tags: python-2.7

I have few files 
setting.py

```
company='google'
```

another file google.py

```
details = {'location':'usa', 'stock':948}
```

and main.py

```
 import setting
print setting.company
profile = __import__(setting.company)
print profile.details

class test():
    def pd (self,details):
        self.param=details
        print self.param
        print profile.details
        print profile.details['stock']
        self.next_method()
    def next_method(self):
        print "in next_method"
        print profile.self.param

t1=test()
t1.pd('details')
```

when I try to print dict variable from google.py with self , it give me an error . 
I need to get dict variables . My script o/p is

```
python main.py 
google
{'location': 'usa', 'stock': 948}
details
{'location': 'usa', 'stock': 948}
948
in next_method
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    t1.pd('details')
  File "main.py", line 12, in pd
    self.next_method()
  File "main.py", line 15, in next_method
    print profile.self.param
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'self'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This doesn't look like you're using OOP the way it is intended.

Comment: i did import of google.py . I want to print dict variable 'details' from google.py.  I am passing 'details' as value of variable (self.param='details'). Code modified to explain my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're doing is quite a strange thing and the dynamic importing you're trying to do should probably be avoided. It is likely that what you're trying to create can be done in a better way (why for example not all the information in a single config file?). Nonetheless an example:

```
from pprint import pprint
import setting
profile = __import__(setting.company).details

class Company(object):
    def __init__(self, name, details):
        self.name = name
        self.details = details

    def printDict(self):
        print(self.name+'\n============\n')
        pprint(self.details)

t1 = Company(setting.company, profile)
t1.printDict()
```